# how to open a web address, and print the page with batch/VB script?

Tags: printing, batch-file

I am new to batch script, please suggest what to do with the following question.

I want to load a web page, then print 2 copies of the webpage to a printer using batch/VB script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a vbscript that will do it. Change the site variable to whatever site you want to print.

```
'Print Webpage
On Error Resume Next

Dim oIE 
Dim NumPages
Dim Site
Const OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2

NumPages = 2
Site = "www.google.com"

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Navigate Site
oIE.Visible = 1

Do while oIE.ReadyState <> 4
    wscript.sleep 1000
Loop

For x = 1 to NumPages
    oIE.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER
Next
```

Comment: thanks for this great example, i have tried it, do you mind give me a little explanation for example: OLECMDID_PRINT? thanks a lot.

Comment: That's just a constant for ExecWB that is equal to 6. It's the equivalent of clicking File|Print in IE. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691264(v=vs.85).aspx) is the complete list of constants with explanations.